# Time lag in cell selection app - Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the script below to help me navigate what cell I'm on.

It works, but there's a lag. Is there anything that would speed it up?

What I really want to do is just highlight the border of the current cell more clearly, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Thanks!

```
 function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, maxRows, maxColumns).setBackground(null);
  sheet.getRange(1, range.getColumn(), maxRows, 1).setBackground("yellow");
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, maxColumns).setBackground("yellow");
}
```

Comment: The fastest way to go is to learn how to use the event object

Comment: Try `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` to learn more about event object

Answer (score 0):

If you simply do this you will notice a delay.  So I believe there is no way to improve the performance.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  range.setBackground("yellow");
}
```